# spyder set python interpreter at launch

Tags: virtualenv, spyder, pythoninterpreter

I am trying to use Spyder with virtual environments. I have installed spyder-kernels and after launching Spyder, I can go into the gui and point to the correct python interpreter. Is there a way this can be done at launch so I don't have to go into the gui every time and update the interpreter when I change environment?

Comment: As I couldn't find how to do this either, I submitted a feature request:
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16299

Comment: yeah, that would be a nice feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the answer you're looking for... but I was able to accomplish this by creating a script that modifies the following files before launching spyder. These two files are what get changed when you interactively change the interpreter in the preferences.

- The `main_interpreter` section in `~/.config/spyder-py3/config/transient.ini`. For example, if your venv path is `PATH`, then

  ```
  [main_interpreter]
  custom_interpreters_list = ['PATH/bin/python']
  custom_interpreter = PATH/bin/python
  executable = PATH/bin/python
  ```
- Enable the custom interpreter in the `main_interpreter` section in `~/.config/spyder-py3/config/spyder.ini`

  ```
  [main_interpreter]
  default = False
  custom = True
  ```

This is on linux - the .ini files may be on a different path in Windows.

Comment: This will work. Did similar editing in the ini file in windows using a python script. Nice!